# Google Nearby Messages API Broke App Icon

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-api, google-nearby

After pod installing NearbyMessages and reinstall the app on the simulator or physical iOS device my app icon goes blank.

I am using swift 3.2 and XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b). I am using 
 NearbyMessages version 1.1.0.

Comment: Sometimes just restart your devices as it has a catch in it and it might work. 
let me know if the fix work thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried everything and its 100% related to the nearby messages pod and the latest version of the iOS.  It seems to work fine on my simulator with iOS 9.  Makes me wonder what google is doing in that sneaky, huge libGNSMessages.a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you open the xcworkspace check the app icon folder and see if there is an image in that and does it match the [apples guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The app icon works just fine before pod installing nearby messages.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 11.2, when I install NearbyMessages via Cocoapods, I get an error:

> warning: duplicate output file '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-bcwvmondqpgllhdzdahpqecjlqca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/Assets.car' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-bcwvmondqpgllhdzdahpqecjlqca/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XXX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.build/Script-F8B92903BE89C5535684B7F8.sh (in target 'XXX' from project ‘XXX')

This suggests that there’s some conflict in assets. This might explain app icon issues.

Comment: FWIW, when I use the legacy build system, this error goes away. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808578/google-nearbymessages-cocoapod-generates-duplicate-output-file-error.